# Tcl 8.4 CSV Function

Tags: tcl

I am struggling to come up with a repeatable solution for this that can work with different headers or CSV formats. I am running it on a device with TCL 8.4 that cannot be changed to a newer version.

I have data in a CSV format:

```
Name,Interface,Description,IP,Mask
sw1,G1/0/1,to_sw2,192.168.0.1,255.255.255.252
sw1,G1/0/2,to_sw3,192.168.0.5,255.255.255.252
sw2,G1/0/1,to_sw1,192.168.0.2,255.255.255.252
```

I want to create a function that takes three inputs: the actual value of "Name," the actual value of "Interface," and the name of the column. The function should output the value of the column that matches the values of the first two columns.

For example:

```
set IP [processCSV sw1 G1/0/1 IP]
```

The expected output should be "192.168.0.1".

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Here's two functions based on whether or not I'm using one or two titles to match.

```
set list {Name,Description,IP,Mask
sw1,to_sw2,192.168.0.1,255.255.255.0
sw2,to_sw3,192.168.0.2,255.255.255.0
sw3,to_sw1,192.168.0.3,255.255.255.0}

proc csv {list title header} {
    set listSplit [split $list \n]
    set headers [split [lindex $listSplit 0] ,]
    set i [lsearch -exact $headers $header]
    foreach entry $listSplit {
        set entry [split $entry ,]
        if {[string compare $title [lindex $entry 0]]==0} {
            set row $entry
        }
    }
    return [lindex $row $i]
}

set Mask [csv $list sw1 Mask]

set csvData "Name,Interface,Description,IP,Mask
sw1,G1/0/1,to_sw2,192.168.0.1,255.255.255.0
sw2,G1/0/1,to_sw1,192.168.0.2,255.255.255.0"

proc csv2 {list title title2 header} {
    set listSplit [split $list \n]
    set headers [split [lindex $listSplit 0] ,]
    set i [lsearch -exact $headers $header]
    foreach entry $listSplit {
        set entry [split $entry ,]
        if {[string compare $title [lindex $entry 0]]==0} {
            if {[string compare $title2 [lindex $entry 1]]==0} {
                set row $entry
            }
        }
    }
    return [lindex $row $i]
}
set Mask [csv2 $csvData sw1 G1/0/1 Description]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since "name,interface" is the unique key, I'd use an array with a compound key:

```
proc parse_csv {filename array_name} {
    upvar $array_name ary
    array set ary {}
    set fh [open $filename r]
    set headers [split [gets $fh] ,]

    while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
        set fields [split $line ,]
        foreach {name interface} [lrange $fields 0 1] break

        for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $fields]} {incr i} {
            set key "$name,$interface,[lindex $headers $i]"
            set ary($key) [lindex $fields $i]
        }
    }
    close $fh
}

proc get_field {array_name name interface field} {
    upvar $array_name ary
    set key "$name,$interface,$field"
    return $ary($key)
}

set filename "file.csv"
parse_csv $filename my_data

puts [get_field my_data "sw1" "G1/0/2" IP]

parray my_data
```

outputs

```
192.168.0.5
my_data(sw1,G1/0/1,Description) = to_sw2
my_data(sw1,G1/0/1,IP)          = 192.168.0.1
my_data(sw1,G1/0/1,Interface)   = G1/0/1
my_data(sw1,G1/0/1,Mask)        = 255.255.255.252
my_data(sw1,G1/0/1,Name)        = sw1
my_data(sw1,G1/0/2,Description) = to_sw3
my_data(sw1,G1/0/2,IP)          = 192.168.0.5
my_data(sw1,G1/0/2,Interface)   = G1/0/2
my_data(sw1,G1/0/2,Mask)        = 255.255.255.252
my_data(sw1,G1/0/2,Name)        = sw1
my_data(sw2,G1/0/1,Description) = to_sw1
my_data(sw2,G1/0/1,IP)          = 192.168.0.2
my_data(sw2,G1/0/1,Interface)   = G1/0/1
my_data(sw2,G1/0/1,Mask)        = 255.255.255.252
my_data(sw2,G1/0/1,Name)        = sw2
```